# trying to match a column with a list of column names to a table that has those columns with their own values SQL

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have a table A that is a singular column called "Column_Name" and its values are a list of names. I have another table B whose columns are those values of "Column_Name" in table A. For example the values of "Column_Name" in table A are (Date, Age, Location). Then in table B, its actual columns are (Date, Age, Location) and those columns have their own respective values. I am trying to select the columns from table B that are values in "Column_Name" in table A. Is there a way to do this? I think I can use the IN operator in a WHERE clause, but not exactly sure how.

Comment: You're talking about dynamic SQL. This is probably a really bad idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it correctly,
Considering that the column_name in tableA is separated by commas,
would it be something like this?

```
select * from tableB 
    where Dt in (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column_Name,',',1) from tableA) 
           or Age in (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column_Name,',',2) from tableA)
           or Location in (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(Column_Name,',',3) from tableA);
```

here is the example
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pUytYwKpK4mRsk76oFonV8/0